# Can't install Graalvm native-image on ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I've just downloaded and installed graalvm-ce-java11-21.3.0. By default Native Image is not available, so I need to add it. So I ran this command,

```
gu install native-image
```

I got this error:

```
Downloading: Release index file from oca.opensource.oracle.com
Downloading: Component catalog from www.graalvm.org
Processing Component: Native Image
Downloading: Component native-image: Native Image  from github.com
Installing new component: Native Image (org.graalvm.native-image, version 21.3.0)
Installation of Native Image failed: /home/deehaz/Downloads/graalvm-ce-java11-21.3.0/lib/graal_isolate.h: Operation not permitted
I/O error occurred: /home/deehaz/Downloads/graalvm-ce-java11-21.3.0/lib/graal_isolate.h: Operation not permitted
```

Please, can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://askubuntu.com/questions/54525/chown-changing-ownership-of-operation-not-permitted

Answer (score 2):

How to Install GraalVM Community Edition on Linux

Note: Tested on Ubuntu 20 only

1. Download the [new release of GraalVM](https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases) and unpack it anywhere in your filesystem:

```
$wget https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/download/vm-22.0.0.2/graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-22.0.0.2.tar.gz

$ tar -xvzf graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-22.0.0.2.tar.gz
```

2. Move the unpacked dir to `/usr/lib/jvm/` and create a symbolic link to make your life easier when updating the GraalVM version:

if the `jvm` folder does not exist run the command

```
$ mkdir /usr/lib/jvm
```

```
$ mv graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-22.0.0.2/ /usr/lib/jvm/
$ cd /usr/lib/jvm
$ ln -s graalvm-ce-java11-linux-amd64-22.0.0.2 graalvm
```

3. Configure ~/.bashrce:

```
$vim ~/.bashrc
```

paste the content

```
#gralvm configuration
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/graalvm/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/graalvm/
```

reload the edited file

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

4. Testing

To make sure everything is working fine, set the new JVM on your environment:

```
java -version
```

To verify, just check the version number:

```
openjdk version "11.0.14" 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.0.0.2 (build 11.0.14+9-jvmci-22.0-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.0.0.2 (build 11.0.14+9-jvmci-22.0-b05, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And you're set.

5. install native-image.

```
gu install native-image
```

hope i helped you..

Answer (score 0):

It seems i accidentally downloaded and extracted GraalVM installation as root and then tried to install Native Image as normal user.